# SPFx app after updating node version app not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, error, spfx-tooling

I created SPFx app in node version 8.x and deployed successfully. Now I want to do enhancement to the app but node does not allow to build app when because of 8.x node version.

So I update the node version to 16.x(LTS) and now the app is not working it's keep on showing error. I have tried the below steps by commands:

1. npm outdated
2. update to latest version
3. npm install
4. gulp clean

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Node.js version 16.x is not yet supported for SPFx development.

Node.js version to use is depend on the version of SPFx generator you are using.

For example: If you are using SPFx v1.14, you can use Node.js version LTS v12 or LTS v14

[image]

I would recommend you to check & follow the SPFx compatibility matrix given at: [SharePoint Framework development tools and libraries compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Use NVM to Update Your Node Version

With NVM, you can install Node versions and specify the version of Node that a project uses. NVM makes it easy to test projects across various Node versions.

To update a Node Version with NVM, you have to install NVM first.